# jQuery - When one card is hovered or has focus, blur the other

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jquery so when a div and/or it's contents are hovered or has focus, the other div's with the same class will be blurred (css3).

And then on mouse out or lost focus, all should be unblurred.

The html looks like this (simplified):

```
<div class="card"><input type="text"></div>
<div class="card"><input type="text"></div>
<div class="card"><input type="text"></div>
```

I appreciate any ideas. Thank you

Comment: Just as an aside to help, only one element can have focus at one time. Additionally, technically more than one element can be hovered at a time if the elements have a parent-child relationship to each other (hovering a child will also activate hover on the child's parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `.siblings()`, `.toggleClass()` to toggle `className` of siblings of hovered element, `css` `filter` set to `blur(npx)` where `n` is position number representing `px` unit.

```js
$(".card").hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings().toggleClass("hover")
})
```

```css
.card.hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="card"><input type="text">card</div>
  <div class="card"><input type="text">card</div>
  <div class="card"><input type="text">card</div>
```

To use only `css` you can place `.card` elements within a container element; set container element `css` to `filter:blur(0px)` using selector `.container .card:not(:hover)`, set `.container:hover .card:not(:hover)` selector to `filter:blur(npx)`

```css
.container:hover .card:not(:hover) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"><input type="text">card</div>
  <div class="card"><input type="text">card</div>
  <div class="card"><input type="text">card</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I love the css one! I did not know that.. Thank you very much